# Access to REST Sharepoint data from another domain

Tags: rest, sharepoint, cors

Have this question: how I can do REST calls to Sharepoint 2013/2016 REST api, from another host, lets say, another server, but within the same domain.

By default, CORS policy will deny any request that does not come from the same host.

I am trying to retrieve some information doing an AJAX REST request from another host.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable SharePoint configure to enable cross domain access.

Below script is shared by Ingo Karstein [here](https://blog.kenaro.com/2014/03/18/cross-site-scripting-with-sharepoint-2013-rest-calls/)

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0

$localFarm = Get-SPFarm

$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://sp:12001"

# Remove old web.config modifications of MyAuthenticationProvider
$oldMods = @();
$webapp.WebConfigModifications | ? { $_.Owner -eq "CrossSiteScripting" } | % { 
    $oldMods = $oldMods + $_
}

$oldMods | % { 
    $webapp.WebConfigModifications.Remove($_) 
}

# update the Web Application and apply all existing web.config modifications - this executes the "remove" actions from above
$webapp.Update()
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService.ApplyWebConfigModifications()

#Wait until web.config modifications finished by timer job
while( (Get-SPTimerJob | ? { $_.Name -eq "job-webconfig-modification"}) -ne $null ) {
    Write-Host "." -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep 1
}

# New web.config modifications for MyAuthenticationProvider
$myModification1 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$myModification1.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders"
$myModification1.Name = "add[@name='Access-Control-Allow-Origin'][@value='http://wfm:13002']"
$myModification1.Sequence = 0
$myModification1.Owner = "CrossSiteScripting"
#0 = for the enum value "SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode"
$myModification1.Type = 0
$myModification1.Value = "<add name='Access-Control-Allow-Origin' value='http://wfm:13002' />"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($myModification1)

$myModification1 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$myModification1.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders"
$myModification1.Name = "add[@name='Access-Control-Request-Method'][@value='GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS']"
$myModification1.Sequence = 0
$myModification1.Owner = "CrossSiteScripting"
$myModification1.Type = 0
$myModification1.Value = "<add name='Access-Control-Request-Method' value='GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS' />"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($myModification1)

$myModification1 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$myModification1.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders"
$myModification1.Name = "add[@name='Access-Control-Request-Headers'][@value='Content-Type,Authorization']"
$myModification1.Sequence = 0
$myModification1.Owner = "CrossSiteScripting"
$myModification1.Type = 0
$myModification1.Value = "<add name='Access-Control-Request-Headers' value='Content-Type,Authorization' />"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($myModification1)

$myModification1 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
$myModification1.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders"
$myModification1.Name = "add[@name='Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'][@value='true']"
$myModification1.Sequence = 0
$myModification1.Owner = "CrossSiteScripting"
$myModification1.Type = 0
$myModification1.Value = "<add name='Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' value='true' />"
$webapp.WebConfigModifications.Add($myModification1)

$webapp.Update()
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService.ApplyWebConfigModifications()

#Wait until web.config modifications finished by timer job
while( (Get-SPTimerJob | ? { $_.Name -eq "job-webconfig-modification"}) -ne $null ) {
    Write-Host "." -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep 1
}
```

My test result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" onclick="getListItems()" value="button" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getListItems() {
            var dataEndPoint = "http://sp:12001/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Versions')/items";
                    $.ajax({
                        url: dataEndPoint,
                        type: "GET",
                        headers: {
                            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"                                                     
                        },
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data.d.results.length);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    })
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]